# inlineKeyboard on telegram for send to channel

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram

I'm trying to use telegram bot and it can send messages to telegram channels with inline keyboards.

But when I used switch_inline_query I ran into a problem and an error occurred:

> "error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: BUTTON_TYPE_INVALID"

so is use of switch_inline_query in channels prohibited?

Comment: Can you post the code with which you are trying to send the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this queston from telegram support,
switch_inline_query is prohibited to use in channels yet.
Thanks